Most Efficient Way To Add Email Field of Auth User Model From A ManyToMany Field When Sending Email
In the code below I would like to add the email of the user's email field directly into the recipient's variable below in the notification function. How would one achieve this?
class Pass(models.Model):
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False,verbose_name="Guest")
    date = models.DateField(blank=False,null=False,verbose_name='Date')
    area = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False,verbose_name='Area(s)')
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False,verbose_name="Member")
    member_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14,blank=False,null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128,blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='pass_users',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='passes',
        blank=True,
        limit_choices_to = {'is_active': True})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.guest_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('guestpass:pass_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

@receiver(post_save, sender=Pass)
def notification(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        subject = 'New Guest Pass'
        message = '%s guest pass has been created.' %(instance.guest_name)
        sender = 'noreply@email.com'
        recipients = [?]
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            sender,
            recipients,
            fail_silently=False,
        )


Pass have email field. you can set recipients = [instance.email]
